# docker-compose pull command fails with pull access denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I am using gitlab private registry. As part of the CI/CD job. I login with the CI_REGISTRY_USER as well a token with all the access enabled to gitlab. (tried these two logins instructions separately)

```
echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY

docker login -u "gitlab-deploy-token" -p "xxxxxxxxxx" $CI_REGISTRY
```

then start by taking down the currently running service containers and followed by an image pull.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml down --remove-orphans
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml --verbose pull
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml up -d --no-build --abort-on-container-exit
```

If I remove the pull instruction everything works correctly. Here is the output of the docker-compose pull. I tried the above instructions with token that is given by Gitlab as well as one created by me (see above). It still doesn't work. It always gives me `pull access denied`.

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here ?

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml --verbose pull
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.dev.yaml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/gitlab-runner/.docker/config.json', '/home/gitlab-runner/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: /home/gitlab-runner/.docker/config.json
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'auths' section
docker.auth.parse_auth: Found entry (registry='gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567', username='gitlab-deploy-token')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.38/version HTTP/1.1" 200 865
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
docker-py version: 4.1.0
CPython version: 3.7.5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localhost
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': 'Docker Engine - Community'}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '19.03.6', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.40', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2020-02-13T01:26:21.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'false', 'GitCommit': '369ce74a3c', 'GoVersion': 'go1.12.16', 'KernelVersion': '4.15.0-106-generic', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}, {'Name': 'containerd', 'Version': '1.2.10', 'Details': {'GitCommit': 'b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339'}}, {'Name': 'runc', 'Version': '1.0.0-rc8+dev', 'Details': {'GitCommit': '3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657'}}, {'Name': 'docker-init', 'Version': '0.18.0', 'Details': {'GitCommit': 'fec3683'}}], Version=19.03.6, ApiVersion=1.40, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=369ce74a3c, GoVersion=go1.12.16, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.15.0-106-generic, BuildTime=2020-02-13T01:26:21.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('docker_backend')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.38/networks/docker_backend HTTP/1.1" 404 52
Pulling postgresql             ... 
Pulling core-application ... 
Pulling frontend         ... 
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Service: postgresql>, <Service: frontend>, <Service: core-application>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: postgresql>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker pull <- ('gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567/webapp/custom-postgres', tag='latest', stream=True, platform=None)
docker.auth.get_config_header: Looking for auth config
docker.auth.resolve_authconfig: Looking for auth entry for 'gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567'
docker.auth.resolve_authconfig: Found 'gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567'
docker.auth.get_config_header: Found auth config
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: frontend>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker pull <- ('gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567/webapp/frontend/devops-pipeline-tests', tag='latest', stream=True, platform=None)
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: core-application>
docker.auth.get_config_header: Looking for auth config
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker pull <- ('gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567/webapp/core-application/devops-pipeline-tests', tag='latest', stream=True, platform=None)
docker.auth.resolve_authconfig: Looking for auth entry for 'gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567'
docker.auth.get_config_header: Looking for auth config
docker.auth.resolve_authconfig: Found 'gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567'
docker.auth.resolve_authconfig: Looking for auth entry for 'gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567'
docker.auth.get_config_header: Found auth config
docker.auth.resolve_authconfig: Found 'gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567'
docker.auth.get_config_header: Found auth config
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.38/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=gitlab.xxxx.fi%3A4567%2Fwebapp%2Fcore-application%2Fdevops-pipeline-tests HTTP/1.1" 404 216
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Failed: <Service: core-application>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.38/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=gitlab.xxxx.fi%3A4567%2Fwebapp%2Fcustom-postgres HTTP/1.1" 404 193
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Failed: <Service: postgresql>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.38/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=gitlab.xxxx.fi%3A4567%2Fwebapp%2Ffrontend%2Fdevops-pipeline-tests HTTP/1.1" 404 208
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Failed: <Service: frontend>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
ERROR: for core-application  pull access denied for gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567/webapp/core-application/devops-pipeline-tests, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
ERROR: for postgresql  pull access denied for gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567/webapp/custom-postgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
ERROR: for frontend  pull access denied for gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567/webapp/frontend/devops-pipeline-tests, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
compose.cli.errors.log_api_error: pull access denied for gitlab.xxxx.fi:4567/webapp/frontend/devops-pipeline-tests, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: please post `docker-compose.dev.yaml`.  I'm a newb to docker-compose, but I guess I'm not following why you need the pull at all- shouldn't `up` take care of it?

Comment: @Frank I want to explicitly log the pull if there was an updates to the images or not. The question is about gitlab-ci job. I have no issues with the `docker-compose.dev.yaml`.

Comment: That seems reasonable.  Looking at your log here...I don't understand `urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None`.  Why would docker-compose be talking to HTTP on localhost?  That seems odd.

Comment: @Frank I am not sure, that is why I am here :)

Comment: This is complex enough that I would ask on the mailing list.  I don't know where to make heads or tails of the issues.  Are you behind a proxy or direct connect?

Comment: @Frank No I am not behind a proxy. If that was the case then both the other instructions should never work. Which mailing list are you talking about ? I guess it is probably a gitlab-ci issue or something. I can pull locally without an issue. It doesn't apply since the gitlab-ci-runner machine is running the jobs and it is hosted in the cloud.

Comment: List [mentioned here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/help/). Proxies can be very finicky and it's possible to have a half-working setup.  Seen it many times.